# Forward data incoming from another machine using srsUE

Tags: networking, routing, exec

I have a srsRAN setup which includes srsUE (srsRAN_4G), srsgnb (srsRAN_Project) and 5Gcore (open5gs) everything running in the same Ubuntu machine. I can send data from the UE to the core by using the following command: `sudo ip netns exec ue1 ping -i 0.1 10.45.1.1`

However, instead of using a generation of ping packets, I would like to send to 10.45.1.1 specific packets incoming from another machine through the wireless interface (via zmq). How can I modify (or add another command) to forward those packets as sender ue1 and destination 10.45.1.1?

The idea is modifying the above command ip netns exec to forward for instance packets from another machine connect to the same WiFi network with IP 192.168.1.35

Thanks!

Comment: You have to link the two network namespaces in order to do routing. That's usually done using veth interfaces (but that's not the only type allowing this). As I'm not sure what's done I'd wait for more details added to the question.